# Configure virtual directory with forward slash with IIS Express

Tags: iis-express

I have configured IIS Express to have multiple virtual directories with a forward slash in the path by editing applicationhost.config.  Is this the only way to have a path with a forward slash - hand edit the config file?

```
<virtualDirectory path="/docs/patha" physicalPath="\\unc\a\d" />
<virtualDirectory path="/docs/pathb" physicalPath="\\unc\b\d" />
<virtualDirectory path="/docs/pathc" physicalPath="\\unc\c\d" />
<virtualDirectory path="/docs/pathd" physicalPath="\\unc\d\d" />
```

Comment: What syntax have you tried with `appcmd.exe` and how does it fail?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf: I did not use appcmd.exe, I used Visual Studio 2013